# Insufficient Privileges Error while creating a Instead of Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a view on which i need to create a Trigger whenever there is an insert action on the view. When i try to create a Instead of Trigger, i get an error saying that i have insufficient Privileges. Isn't it that when i create a trigger, select privileges are enough? If not, what are the privileges required to create this Trigger.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To create a trigger in your own schema on a table in your own schema
>   or on your own schema (SCHEMA), you must have the CREATE TRIGGER
>   system privilege.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm