# ORA-01031 despite insteadof trigger

Tags: oracle, view, triggers, privileges

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.2.0:

As user u1:

```
create table t(a int);
grant select on t to u2;
```

As user u2:

```
create view v as select * from u1.t;
create trigger tr instead of update on v for each row begin null; end;
update v set a = null;
```

Result of executing the update statement as u2:

```
Expected: 0 rows updated.
Actual:   ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Why does u2 get ORA-01031? It's not attempting to update data in t.
What is my workaround? I don't want u2 to have update pivileges on t.

Thanks, Al

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insufficient Privileges Error while creating a Instead of Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468061/insufficient-privileges-error-while-creating-a-instead-of-trigger)

Comment: Privileges checking is happening upon statement parsing. So in your case instead of trigger will not fire. Simply grant `update` privilege on the base table to `u2` user. Only when an update statement passes security checks, the instead of trigger will fire *instead of* that `update` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated, u2 has no business updating u1.t . Is there another workaround?

Comment: Work around for what? If as you said, and I quote `u2 has no business updating u1.t` then why are you trying to update `t` table (through view - you still update base table, which is `t`) connected as user `u2`? View by itself is nothing more than a stored `select` statement. Any `DML` statement executed against that view affects base table(s).

Comment: I'm trying to update the view v, not the table t. The existence of _instead of_ triggers suggests that one is not necessarily connected to the other.

Comment: It's still the base table that's being updated. The point of an `instead of` trigger is that it's executed "instead of" the triggering statement. Imagine a more complex view, which joins multiple tables - the trigger contains the logic which allows inserted or updated data values to be directed to the appropriate tables and columns.

Comment: @Bacs: I understand. Imagine that updates on your complex view only affect some of the joined tables, because the other tables are static code tables or something. Why would you need update privileges on the static tables also in order to update the view? You are not trying to update them. So, what is my workaround in that case?

Comment: I understand your differentiation between tables in the view which you are and aren't updating, but I think Oracle simply doesn't make the same distinction. As Nicholas Krasnov said above, the privileges have already been checked before the trigger fires. They must therefore be based on all the tables in the view.

Comment: Can I suggest you edit your original question, expand your example view to include a mix of tables on which you do and don't want to grant update, and maybe give a real world example of why you would want to do this? I think there might be a good question in here trying to get out, but currently it just begs another question - "why bother?" - which is probably putting off potentially interesting answers.

Comment: My business case is rather complicated and it would take a lot of everybody's time to read it. I thought I was doing the right thing by distilling the problem down to the most simple error case. And I am really interested in an answer to this particular problem as stated. If the answer is that this is just an Oracle limitation and that there is no workaround for it, then I am ready to accept that as an answer. I can then work on a different approach to my business problem, but I didn't want to go down that route without asking first whether this a wellknown problem with a wellknown workaround.

Answer (score 0):

http://psoug.org/definition/authid.htm

Note that for an invoker rights routine referred to in a VIEW or TRIGGER, the owner of these objects is always considered to be the invoker, not the user triggering it.

Meaning if you use a trigger then the procedure will be called with current_user authid. The update trigger itself needs an update priv, because it examines update for table in user1.

For me this is a bug, cause in the end the instead of trigger of the view in schema of user2 has necessaryly nothing to do with the update priv of user1.